# Migration from non-FIPS to FIPS BC jar

Tags: bouncycastle

We have an application which has data already encrypted using non-FIPS Bouncy castle jar which is “bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.jar” with algorithm as “AES/CBC/ PKCS7Padding”, now we want to make this application FIPS complaint and so are planning to use "bc-fips" jar, we would be continuing to use the same algorithm without loosing the data which is already encrypted using non-FIPS BC .

I tested this with a sample data and it seems to be working, looking for any official article/documentation from Bouncy castle confirming that there would be no data loss if we try to encrypt data using non-fips jar and decrypt it using fips jar.